# How to upload multiple files using CI but only save once to database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm new using PHP CI framework. In my project, I have multiple upload input.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('upload_img/om_telolet_om'); ?>">
<input type="text" id="student_id" name="student_id" />
<input type="text" id="arr_img_student" name="arr_img_student" />

<input class="up_img" type="file" name="image1" /><br />
<input class="up_img" type="file" name="image2" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Then, I use jQuery to populate the value of `up_img` and put it in `arr_img_student`. The data then is sent to controller. This is the controller:

```
//UPLOAD
public function om_telolet_om()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');

    //UPLOAD FILE RULES 
    $config['upload_path']     = './asset/images/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size']     = '0';
    $config['max_width']        = '1024';
    $config['max_height']   = '768';
    $config['overwrite']        = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    for($x = 1; $x<=2; $x++){
       $value = "image".$x;

       if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($value)){
            $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();           
            $this->load->view('f_upload', $data);
       }
       else
       {
             $data['id']       = $this->input->post('student_id');
             $data['img_path'] = $this->input->post('arr_img_student');     

             $this->model_student->insert_student($data);           
       }         
    }           
}
```

the code looping the upload but also looping the insert process. **How can I make the code to loop the upload (check upload rules) but only saved once to database ?** The data should be saved if the upload rules is match. In my database, there is only a single table used. `student_id` and `img_path`. I have no privilege changing the database structure.

Comment: "student_id and img_path. I have no privilege changing the database structure." Well if a user can upload many files, this clearly calls for separate table for files and another for users.

Comment: I cannot create another table. That's why I store the image path to a string separated unique text

Comment: sorry but that's not the proper way to store data in an RDBMS

Comment: I know. So, what should I do if I have no privilege to create another table. I have to think another solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$images = array(); // an array to store uploaded images in

for($x = 1; $x<=2; $x++){
   $value = "image".$x;

   if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($value)){
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();           
        $this->load->view('f_upload', $data);
   }
   else
   {
        $filedata = $this->upload->data();

        // Every time a file is uploaded, 
        // add it to the array for saving later
        $images[] = $filedata['full_path'];
   }         
}     

$data['id']       = $this->input->post('student_id');
$data['img_path'] = json_encode($images); // Encode $images array to string

$this->model_student->insert_student($data);
```

Later when using data from the table you will have to decode `img_path` back to array:

```
$student_images = json_decode($data['img_path'], true);
```